# Stretching widgets in column's available space

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I stumbled upon a layout issue that would be rather obvious in native Android, but I cannot make it work in Flutter.

Let's say I have a layout like this:
[Scaffold with AppBar + BottomNavBar + Column + Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8792.png)

And now I want to fill the remaining white space with 2 Widgets (`Containers` in that case, but could be anything), to make it look like this (stretch and take all the **remaining** space): [Column with remaining space filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FDOO.png)

I tried placing `Flex` inside the `Column` and wrapping `Containers` in `Flexible`/`Expanded` with `flex`. But even after wrapping the `Column` in `SizedBox` I still get the constraints error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

Any idea how to achieve that? My code for this screen looks like this currently:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Playground")),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 70,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
              child: Text("I am some text"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
              child: Text("I am some text too"),
            ),
            FlexibleContent(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlexibleContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Flex(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 7, child: Container(width: double.infinity, color: Colors.lightGreen)),
          Expanded(flex: 3, child: Container(width: double.infinity, color: Colors.amberAccent)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your column has an ubounded amount of height, so you have wrap it's child in a expanded/flexible widget. You can have a column with 3 children, 2 of the children that need to be the exact same size could be in a row, and it's children could be wrapped in a expanded/flexible widget.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Playground")),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 70,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
              child: Text("I am some text"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
              child: Text("I am some text too"),
            ),
            Flexible( // sorcery
              child: FlexibleContent(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlexibleContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const FlexibleContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If you add anything in the `Container` it should automatically expand to accommodate the contents. The `Flexible` widget well, makes the other `Column` of widgets, flexible.